# Application error when deploying my Rails app to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I cannot seem to find the error in my rails app.  The app was working fine but after a simple deploy (changing one controller file for an api), not a single page will load.  The logs are of no help either:

```
2018-01-04T18:23:04.899516+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:31202
2018-01-04T18:23:04.899701+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] Use Ctrl-C to stop
2018-01-04T18:23:05.040894+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] - Worker 0 (pid: 12) booted, phase: 0
2018-01-04T18:23:05.043093+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] - Worker 1 (pid: 15) booted, phase: 0
2018-01-04T18:23:05.394579+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2018-01-04T18:23:11+00:00 app[heroku-redis]: source=REDIS sample#active-connections=2 sample#load-avg-1m=0.075 sample#load-avg-5m=0.08 sample#load-avg-15m=0.055 sample#read-iops=0 sample#write-iops=0 sample#memory-total=15664468kB sample#memory-free=12572192kB sample#memory-cached=1275064kB sample#memory-redis=300080bytes sample#hit-rate=0.99862 sample#evicted-keys=0
2018-01-04T18:23:45.338930+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=www..com request_id=d5b547d3-a969-4649-a729-66f9db19eb95 fwd="66.87.124.194" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-01-04T18:23:50.649738+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=www..com request_id=25924358-2142-46d0-8186-c516a6bafcb7 fwd="66.87.124.194" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-01-04T18:23:55.958718+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=www..com request_id=0eeb82f8-5bd8-4a95-bd07-8a9e023ae893 fwd="66.87.124.194" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

any ideas?  I've tried rolling back and that doesn't seem to fix anything?

**Update:**

Without doing anything it randomly started up again?  Why would this happen?

```
2018-01-04T18:27:10.443578+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 24.60.204.37 at 2018-01-04 18:27:10 +0000
2018-01-04T18:27:10.572471+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by StaticPagesController#home_v3 as HTML
2018-01-04T18:27:10.572498+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"secure"=>true}
```

**Update 2:**

It's back down again but the console works (`heroku run rails c`)?

Comment: Anything else in your stack trace? Some documentation is here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h10-app-crashed

Comment: literally nothing, just the app crashed message with no help?

Comment: Now they come out and say it after I've been feverishly trying to figure it out myself: https://status.heroku.com/

Comment: Have you discovered a workaround to get any version of your code running again?

Comment: Honestly, just stop making any changes and it'll come back.  It seems like any new changes made ends up delaying the functionality even further

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a problem with Heroku at this time. Here is a link to their incident report: https://status.heroku.com/incidents/1367

> Since approximately 18:10 UTC (1:10 PM Eastern), application Dynos are failing to start up after releases take place. Our engineers are investigating the cause of this issue.

**Edit** Could be coincidence, but I was restarting our app periodically, and now it is back up again. [One person worked around this](https://twitter.com/drakerehfeld/status/949000035852746752) by beefing up a non-production instance and routing traffic to it.